# How to convert a ios 5 storyboard from ipad to iphone?

Tags: ios5, storyboard

I have designed a group of views using code and Interface builder on iPad running iOS5. The IB use the MainStoryBoard_iPad.storyboard. Now, I will like to use the app on iPhone. I didn´t think I will do this port, but now I want to do it.

**Option 1**
I have tried to, copy the MainStoryBoard_iPad.storyboard, rename to MainStoryBoard_iPhone.storyboard, and launch the app. This work for code, but IB has different ratios, positions, and sizes, and the interface don´t look well.

**Option 2**
I have tried to, copy view, elements, from ipad, and paste on the iphone storyboard, but is not possible, and i think will occur the same thing, problems with sizes.

Someone knows if exist a semi-automatic method to do it?

I consider apply a reduction factor to all app sizes and position, but i have a lot of values to change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are out of luck for a semi-automatic method.

Here is a tutorial describing iPhone to iPad translations.
http://www.raywenderlich.com/1111/how-to-port-an-iphone-application-to-the-ipad

Hope it helps.

Comment: I already found that tutorial, but i need the other step, ipad to iphone. But thanks anyway